# Load resistor scaling for even order Chebyshev BPF

Tags: filter

I need to design an even order Chebyshev BPF for my homework. May I know how to I scale my load resistor value if my source impedance is 50 ohm? Am I supposed to multiply the source impedance with the last column value in the table to get my load impedance?

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Edit:
The filter is designed with load resistance equals to the value suggested by @a concerned citizen. I have run the simulation and try to see the difference between 67.75 ohm load and 50 ohm load but don't see significant difference. Also, if there isn't significant different between 67.75 ohm load and 50 ohm, why don't we just use 50 ohm load? 50 ohm load can also offer matched impedance.

The schematic diagram and simulation result is attached here:
[image: schematic diagram]
[image: simulation result]

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you exactly based on the table you're showing because there's no info attached to it (and I think it's not meant for the load, rather for the multipliers for all the elements in the ladder when building a normal filter), but you can directly use the formula for that:

$$Z_{out}=\dfrac{Z_{in}}{\tanh\left[\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{asinh}\left(\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon_p}\right)\right]^2} \tag{1}$$

This condition is valid irrespective of the filter's order, therefore for a 50 Ω source load and 0.1 dB ripple, the load will have to be calculated as:

$$\begin{align}
\epsilon_p&=\sqrt{10^{A_p/10}-1}\approx 0.153 \tag{2}\\
Z_{out}&=\dfrac{50}{\tanh\left[\dfrac12\mathrm{asinh}\left(\dfrac{1}{0.153}\right)\right]^2}\approx 67.77\;\Omega \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

This is when the first element in the ladder is series; when it's shunt, \$Z_{in}\$ will have to be multiplied, not divided.

Note that using any load higher than it will not cause explosions, it will simply distort the response. To show what happens, here is a sweep for orders from 2 through 7 (taken from [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/519158/95619)) when the condition is met (same load resistor for all the orders):

[image: match]

...versus same loads for both the input and the output:

[image: no match]

---

To be more clear, \$Z_{in}\$ can be either divided or multiplied with the coefficient \$k\$ to give \$Z_{out}\$, but, for example, when the first element is series inductor and \$Z_{in}\$ is multiplied by \$k\$ then the response will still be Chebyshev, but more attenuated. Therefore it doesn't make sense to use multiplication for the series element, unless more attenuation is desired. Here's how a 4th order Chebyshev with 0.1 dB ripple looks like when the output impedance is divided, or multiplied by the value of the input impedance, 50 Ω:

[image: divmult]

The black trace is with 67.77 Ω and the blue trace is with 36.89 Ω.

---

---

If you'll zoom in the passband you'll notice that the two cases you are showing are different. But that's not all: what you did was you calculated the filter for the certain values for the I/O impedances, but then you tested the two cases with *different* loads while not adapting the filter's LC values -- that's not the recommended approach. Let's take them one at a time.

First, the bandpass is derived from the lowpass and, as shown above, the frequency response for a Chebyshev LP of even order doesn't start at \$1\$, but at \$1-\delta_p\$ (where \$1\$ is relative to the input). Since this is a passive filter, the output will be dictated by the resistive divider formed by the I/O impedances. If these are equal, then the output will be half. But since the even order Chebyshev needs to start at \$1-\delta_p\$ it means that there is a physical impossibility in having both a Chebyshev response and equally terminated loads. This is why for the even order filters the \$\varepsilon_p\$ term is included, and it's derived from the condition of the maximum amplitude:

$$A_{max}\le 20\log_{10}\left(\dfrac{R_S+R_L}{2\sqrt{R_SR_L}}\right) \tag{4}$$

Consider the condition met, so then:

$$\begin{align}
10^{A_p/20}&=\dfrac{R_S+R_L}{2\sqrt{R_SR_L}} &\Rightarrow \\
0&=(R_S+R_L)^2-4R_SR_L10^{A_p/10}& \\
R_{L_{1,2}}&=R_S\left[-1\pm 2\left(\sqrt{10^{A_p/5}-10^{A_p/10}}+10^{A_p/10}\right)\right] \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

People far smarter than me were able to see the inclusion of (2) in (5), as well as trigonometric equivalences that lead to (3), but the important part is that the results are the same (the decreasing ones are `tanh()` and `-1-(...)`, while the increasing ones are `1/tanh()` and `-1+(...)`):

[image: same]

Now, this is for the LP, but the BP is derived from it by considering \$f_p\$ to be the center of the BP. If that doesn't seem intuitive, then consider that a BP is a LP+HP. Therefore the same considerents apply for \$f_c\$ in a BP as they do for \$f_p\$ in a LP.

Second, as you know, a passive filter has the downside that the I/O impedances influence the elements, as well as the elements, themselves, each other. Therefore the correct methodology of designing a filter is by including the I/O impedances *everytime*. What you did was you calculated the filter with certain values for the I/O, then you changed the load but used the same calculated filter. From a practical aspect, that may be acceptable for a certain range (tolerances & co), close to the calculated values, but it's not good practice.

So, considering the two points above, here are the frequency responses for two 8th order Chebyshev filters with 0.1 dB in the passband, one designed for 50 Ω input and 50/k Ω output (black traces), and the other designed for equally terminated values of 50 Ω (blue traces). The loads for both filters are the same 50/k Ω, where k is stepped between these values:

```
.step param x list 0.73781, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.35536
```

[image: step]

I've shifted the response of the 2nd filter for better visibility. The top-most trace for both black and blue traces correspond to the first, respectively last values in the `.step` list. As you can see, only those are *equi*ripple (that's what a Chebyshev is all about); all the rest are wonky. What's more, the blue traces show higher divergence from the correct response than the black traces, and that's due to the filter being calculated for equally terminated values, instead of adapted output value, while only the load is changed (your approach). Not lastly, while `V(o2)` shows a correct equiripple for the top-most trace -- that's a fortunate case valid only as long as the load is correctly adapted by k.

Comment: It seems like multiplying or dividing the Zin always yields 36.89ohm for load?

Comment: @mike It can't be, the result of the scaling coefficient is `~0.737`.

Comment: Now I realize I wrote the correct formula, but the wrong result. Corrected, and added a clarification. I didn't show it, but normalizing both responses (for the 3rd picture) makes the traces overlap.

Comment: @a concerned citizen Thanks. I used a series configuration and so the load is 67.77 as calculated above. However, the passband ripple is more than 0.1dB, do you know the reason for that?

Comment: @a concerned citizen Also, I think I should expect some problem when I use a 50 ohm load since even order chebyshev should not have equal termination but the graph is just normal. Why is that so?

Comment: @mike The ripple will be set by the filters values, so only you know what those are. And if you say the graph looks normal then that, too, is only up to you to know since you're the only one seeing it. Unless you'll show some values and pictures, there's no way I can answer that. However, I would recommend looking carefully, because even if there are ripples it doesn't mean they are *equi*ripple, or that they start from \$1-\delta_p\$. Compare carefully the first two pictures. The response starts at \$Z_{out}/(Z_{in}+Z_{out})\$ for the equally-terminated loads, in all cases, which is wrong.

Comment: @a concerned citizen I have attached the filter circuit and simulation result above. I have also elaborated on my doubts, hope you take a look at it. Please let me know if there is any other information needed. I really want to understand this. :)

Comment: @mike I've updated my answer, hopefully it addresses your questions. Also, when using the ping operator, `@`, use it with `@<TAB>` to cycle between a list of names. If no name appears then there's no need to use `@`. Otherwise, there should be no spaces in the names, or there will be no notifications. Here I get notified because you're commenting directly under my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a page from D.Johnson and J.Hilburn, "Rapid Practical Designs of Active Filters" (1975), but maybe not. Is it?

Somewhere the design process on your text will give the design impedance of your filters - probably all standardised at 1 Ohm or 100 or 1000 or ... .

To scale to a new impedance multiply resistors by a factor of Znew/Zold and capacitors by a factor of Zold/Znew.

Can't be that easy, surely ?
Try it :-).

The small difference between what you see for 50 Ohms and 67.75 Ohms is (probably) due to the relatively small mismatch when bith imput and output are mistreminated by this relatively small amount.

Comment: Your answer addresses designing the filter, but I understood that it's the value of the load that OP needs. As in: "I know how to calculate the filter, just not the value of the load". Did I misunderstand it?